# Netty: ChannelRead0 is never called

Tags: java, netty, file-transfer

I'm trying to send files from a java server app to a java client app. 
The file seems to be send from the server to the client since I get output like this:

```
...
Transfer progress: 8459452
Transfer progress: 8459452 / 8459452
Transfer complete.
```

The problem seems to be on the client side. `channelReadComplete` is called for every chunk that is sent by the server. But `channelRead0` is never called! Even `channelRead` from the base class (which is not overwritten in my handler) is never called. Any idea what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance!

The client pipeline:

```
ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
p.addLast("Encoder", new ObjectEncoder());
p.addLast( "Decoder", new ObjectDecoder( Integer.MAX_VALUE, ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled( null ) ));
p.addLast("chunkedWriteHandler", new ChunkedWriteHandler());
p.addLast( "FileChunkHandler", new FileChunkHandler());
```

The server pipeline:

```
p.addLast( "Encoder", new ObjectEncoder());
p.addLast( "Decoder", new ObjectDecoder( Integer.MAX_VALUE, ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled( null ) ));
p.addLast( "chunkedWriteHandler", new ChunkedWriteHandler());
p.addLast( "FileSenderHandler", new FileSenderHandler());
```

The FileChunkHandler on the Client:

```
public class FileChunkHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ChunkedFile>{
    @Override protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChunkedFile msg) throws Exception{
        System.out.println( "channelRead0 ++++");
    }

    @Override public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception{
        System.out.println( "channelReadComplete ++++");
        ctx.fireChannelReadComplete();
    }
}
```

The FileSenderHandler on the Server:

public class FileSenderHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{

```
@Override public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception{
    File file = new File( "/Users/kathrinjennifer/Documents/tmp/test/test.mp3" );

    RandomAccessFile raf = null;
    long fileLength = 0;

    try {
        raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ChannelFuture sendFileFuture = null;

    ChunkedFile chunkedFile = new ChunkedFile( raf);
    sendFileFuture = ctx.write( chunkedFile, ctx.newProgressivePromise());
    ctx.flush();

    sendFileFuture.addListener(new ChannelProgressiveFutureListener() {

        @Override
        public void operationProgressed(ChannelProgressiveFuture future, long progress, long total) {
            if (total < 0) { // total unknown
                System.err.println(future.channel() + " Transfer progress: " + progress);
            } else {
                System.err.println(future.channel() + " Transfer progress: " + progress + " / " + total);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelProgressiveFuture future) {
            System.err.println(future.channel() + " Transfer complete.");
        }
    });

    ctx.fireChannelRegistered();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf>` as you will receive bytes.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work... is there anything wrong with my channel pipeline?

Comment: The ObjectDecoder seems to have an influence! If it is commented out, channelRead0 is called. If the `FileChunkHandler` is moved to be the first Handler in the pipeline `channelRead0`is read 3 times (instead of 1 if the ObjectDecoder is commented out and the order is kept)